# I'm the same age as you are. Then...am I age?

Tags: grammar

Greeting from Korea.

I just read a sentence "I'm the same age as you are."

I can not understand it.

I am (the same) age (as you are).

Age can not be a object for be verb. What happened?

Comment: If it helps you, imagine that there's a missing *of*: *I'm (of) the same age*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Comment: @Rathony Thanks for your kindness, between, I've actually visited and asked one question on English Language Learners.

Comment: @Anonym Yeah, man. That "of" just gives me a clue! I got it. Now I can fully understand what I wondered. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Age" is not the object of the verb; it is the predicate complement of the verb.

Consider the following:

> You are 35.
>
> I am 35.
>
> I'm the same age as you are.
>
> You are 180 cm.
>
> I am 180 cm.
>
> I'm the same height as you are.
>
> You are 85 kg.
>
> I am 85 kg.
>
> I'm the same weight as you are.
>
> You are Korean.
>
> I am Korean.
>
> I'm the same nationality as you are.

Comment: First of all, really thank you for your comment! This milk is 3 litres. This water is 3 litres. This milk is the same volume as this water (is). Is it right?

Comment: @Bling. Yes, correct. Like, "This pencil is the same length as that pen."  "This room is the same temperature as that room." etc.